# HTTP Status 403 if I go to the login page after being already logged in (Spring security login)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a login system with Sring mvc. I followed this [example](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/05/spring-security-custom-login-form.html); it works.

But, if I go to the login page after being already logged in, I get this error:

```
HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
type Status report    
message Access is denied    
description Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

I wonder if there is a specific "command" of Spring that allow me to be redirected to a specific page if I'm already logged in and I try to go to the login page.

I dont' add code here, because I think it's easier to you to see it on the link above.

Comment: Oh, I looked for it but i didn't find it. Thank you man

Comment: Try it and post the update you find any issues